# php code inside html in Asp.net mvc remains as it when run

Tags: javascript, php, html, asp.net-mvc

I use Asp.net mvc 5 with c# in Visual Studio 2017, I want to add contact form and the code of the contact contains part in php, javascript and html 
the problem is when I run the page in browser it display the contact form from html and javascript but it leaves the php code written in as it. I means it display lines of php code in the page.

How can I solve this problem?

```js
$('.contact-form form input[type="text"], .contact-form form textarea').on('focus', function () {
        $('.contact-form form input[type="text"], .contact-form form textarea').removeClass('input-error');
    });
    $('.contact-form form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.contact-form form input[type="text"], .contact-form form textarea').removeClass('input-error');
        var postdata = $('.contact-form form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'assets/contact.php',
            data: postdata,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (json) {
                if (json.nameMessage != '') {
                    $('.contact-form form .contact-name').addClass('input-error');
                }
                if (json.emailMessage != '') {
                    $('.contact-form form .contact-email').addClass('input-error');
                }
                if (json.subjectMessage != '') {
                    $('.contact-form form .contact-subject').addClass('input-error');
                }
                if (json.messageMessage != '') {
                    $('.contact-form form textarea').addClass('input-error');
                }
                if (json.nameMessage == '' && json.emailMessage == '' && json.subjectMessage == '' && json.messageMessage == '') {
                    $('.contact-form form').fadeOut('fast', function () {
                        $('.contact-form').append('Thanks for contacting us! We will get back to you very soon.');
                        // reload background
                        $.backstretch("resize");
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="form" action="assets/contact.php" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="contact-name">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name..." class="contact-name form-control" id="contact-name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="contact-email">Email</label>
                            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email..." class="contact-email form-control" id="contact-email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="contact-subject">Subject</label>
                            <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject..." class="contact-subject form-control" id="contact-subject">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="contact-message">Message</label>
                            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message..." class="contact-message form-control" id="contact-message"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn">Send message</button>
                    </form>
                    <?php

                    // Email address verification
                    function isEmail($email) {
                    return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
                    }

                    if($_POST) {
                    // Enter the email where you want to receive the message
                    $emailTo = 'kk@gmail.com';

                    $name = addslashes(trim($_POST['name']));
                    $clientEmail = addslashes(trim($_POST['email']));
                    $subject = addslashes(trim($_POST['subject']));
                    $message = addslashes(trim($_POST['message']));

                    $array = array('nameMessage' => '', 'emailMessage' => '', 'subjectMessage' => '', 'messageMessage' => '');

                    if($name == '') {
                    $array['nameMessage'] = 'Empty name!';
                    }
                    if(!isEmail($clientEmail)) {
                    $array['emailMessage'] = 'Invalid email!';
                    }
                    if($subject == '') {
                    $array['subjectMessage'] = 'Empty subject!';
                    }
                    if($message == '') {
                    $array['messageMessage'] = 'Empty message!';
                    }
                    if($name != '' && isEmail($clientEmail) && $subject != '' && $message != '') {
                    // Send email
                    $message = "Message from: " . $name . "\r\n" . $message;
                    $headers = "From: " . $clientEmail . " <" . $clientEmail . ">" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: " . $clientEmail;
                    mail($emailTo, $subject . " (bootstrap contact form)", $message, $headers);
                    }
                    echo json_encode($array);

                    }
                    ?>
```

Comment: Essentially you are asking asp.net to understand what is PHP code.

Comment: Dear Steve sorry I do not understand what you means, can explain more please

Comment: asp.net and php are two different solutions for the server side rendering. you have either a server which processes asp.net or php but not one which supports both in combination.

Comment: A better explanation needed.